# Is opening a templating engine to users a bad idea?

Tags: security, templates, code-security, server-security

My site allows users to create custom HTML templates for their profiles (very much like Tumblr and the theme system), and I picked the Twig template engine for the site.

However, I'm not sure if it's a good idea to give users the control of being able to access a template engine.

Is this a bad thing? How should I restrict access, or should I just totally rethink the strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Twig homepage](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/):

> **Secure**: Twig has a sandbox mode to evaluate untrusted template code. This allows Twig to be used as a template language for applications where users may modify the template design.

and farther down:

> *Sandboxing*: Twig can evaluate any template in a sandbox environment where the user has access to a limited set of tags, filters, and object methods defined by the developer. Sandboxing can be enabled globally or locally for just some templates:
>
> ```
>  {{ include('page.html', sandboxed = true) }}
> ```

So, all you have to do is sandbox the user templates and you should be fine

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! I have to wait a minute before marking your answer correct but I will when I can.